# How to align/render flutter widgets around a single widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-web

So basically this is what I'm trying to achieve

[image]

WITH THE WIDGET WITH THE RED X BEING THE **ROOT** WIDGET IN WHICH ALL WIDGETS NEEDS TO BE BUILT AROUND IT

All the widgets here are going to be **'rendered'** **dynamically** which means I get their informations from somewhere, so to achieve this I thought of two options:

- Use the Stack widget or another mysterious layout widget I did not find yet
- Use simple columns and rows in which this has created a problem:
  this is the code I'm using

```
 Widget panelWidget(Panel panel) {
   return Row(
     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
     crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
     children: [
       //WIDGETS ON THE LEFT
       ...panel.attachedPanels
           .where((element) => element.attachedToSide == 3)
           .map(
             (e) => Container(
               height: getH(e.panelHeight),
               width: getW(e.panelWidth),
               decoration:
                   BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
             ),
           )
           .toList(),
       Column(
         mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
         children: [
           //WIDGETS ON TOP
           ...panel.attachedPanels
               .where((element) => element.attachedToSide == 2)
               .map(
                 (e) => Container(
                   height: getH(e.panelHeight),
                   width: getW(e.panelWidth),
                   decoration:
                       BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                 ),
               )
               .toList(),
           Center( //THIS IS THE ROOT WIDGET
             child: Container(
               height: getH(panel.panelHeight),
               width: getW(panel.panelWidth),
               decoration:
                   BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
             ),
           ),
           //WIDGETS ON THE BOTTOM
           ...panel.attachedPanels
               .where((element) => element.attachedToSide == 0)
               .map(
                 (e) => Container(
                   height: getH(e.panelHeight),
                   width: getW(e.panelWidth),
                   decoration:
                       BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
                 ),
               )
               .toList(),
         ],
       ),
       //WIDGETS ON THE RITGHT
       ...panel.attachedPanels
           .where((element) => element.attachedToSide == 1)
           .map(
             (e) => Container(
               height: getH(e.panelHeight),
               width: getW(e.panelWidth),
               decoration:
                   BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.black)),
             ),
           )
           .toList(),
     ],
   );
 }
```

please mind the logic as I'm focused now on figuring this out first, you can see bellow the root widget commented and around it from 4 sides there is the list of the widgets I need to render, on paper it looks fine but this is the output, I'm using Flutter Web :
[image]

As you can see the left and right widgets are NOT aligned with the root widget because they are following the Row's cross axis alignment.
Flutter is doing it's job of putting these 2 widgets at the center but the widgets don't have the same size thus shifting the center point a bit for the whole widget tree, I tried different combinations but they all did not work, Any help is highly welcomed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Table`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Table-class.html) widget, which does what you're trying to do for you.

Don't think of building a widget off to the side of another "root" widget. Think of everything in terms of a tree where everything has a parent-child/children relationship. Each of your widgets is at the same level in the tree, they just need the right parent to put them in the right place.

Your desired layout using `Placeholder`s in the `Table` is implemented in the following code. It can be copy-pasted into DartPad.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Table(
      defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
      children: <TableRow>[
        TableRow(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            const SizedBox(),
          ],
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: <Widget>[
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: <Widget>[
            const SizedBox(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            const SizedBox(),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Result:
[image: Result from above code]

---

For accommodating a "dynamic" layout, the changes to the above code are trivial. The following adjusts `MyWidget` to take optional top, bottom, left, and right widgets and adjusts everything accordingly so that the `Table` works correctly.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(
            root: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            top: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            right: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget root;
  final Widget? right, left, top, bottom;

  const MyWidget({
    required this.root,
    this.right,
    this.left,
    this.top,
    this.bottom,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> middleRow = [
      if(left != null)
        left!,
      root,
      if(right != null)
        right!,
    ];
    
    final List<Widget> topRow = [
      if(left != null)
        const SizedBox(),
      top ?? const SizedBox(),
      if(right != null)
        const SizedBox(),
    ];
    
    final List<Widget> bottomRow = [
      if(left != null)
        const SizedBox(),
      bottom ?? const SizedBox(),
      if(right != null)
        const SizedBox(),
    ];
    
    return Table(
      defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
      children: <TableRow>[
        TableRow(
          children: topRow,
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: middleRow,
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: bottomRow,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: "Dynamic" example result]

Or if you want empty space where widgets are omitted:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

final Color darkBlue = Color.fromARGB(255, 18, 32, 47);

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(scaffoldBackgroundColor: darkBlue),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(
            root: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            top: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
            right: SizedBox(
              height: 100,
              child: Placeholder(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget root;
  final Widget? right, left, top, bottom;

  const MyWidget({
    required this.root,
    this.right,
    this.left,
    this.top,
    this.bottom,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final List<Widget> middleRow = [
      left ?? const SizedBox(),
      root,
      right ?? const SizedBox(),
    ];
    
    final List<Widget> topRow = [
      const SizedBox(),
      top ?? const SizedBox(),
      const SizedBox(),
    ];
    
    final List<Widget> bottomRow = [
      const SizedBox(),
      bottom ?? const SizedBox(),
      const SizedBox(),
    ];
    
    return Table(
      defaultVerticalAlignment: TableCellVerticalAlignment.middle,
      children: <TableRow>[
        TableRow(
          children: topRow,
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: middleRow,
        ),
        TableRow(
          children: bottomRow,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Empty space example result]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it answers some questions, however since I'm getting the 'Rows' dynamically , I cant guarantee or know how many widgets will be in a row in which the table has to have the same amount of widgets in each row

Comment: @ExtremeGeek Why is this an issue? Just remove/add rows/columns as necessary. There is nothing preventing you from only using parts of this layout at a time.

Comment: In your example you are filling the empty cells with a ```SizedBox()``` I cannot do that cause everything is dynamic, therefor is there other solutions to my problem ? cause using a table kind of limits the customization that I will have to do later, will a grid be helpful here ?

Comment: @ExtremeGeek What is wrong with filling the empty cells with something that has **no size**? It's unclear what you mean by "dynamic". A `Table` *is* a grid. It's the same as a `GridView`, just without the scrolling.

Comment: What's wrong is that I can't know how many ```SizedBox()```s I need to use to fill the spaces, unless I add lot more code just to check what's the max of cells I have in all the rows

Comment: @ExtremeGeek Would you prefer to implement a table layout algorithm yourself? It's not practical when the hard work is done already. It's trivial to fill in empty spaces with `sizedbox`s. You even already know that your middle row will always have the most columns, which you can use to determine the length of the other rows. This should not be an issue, nor will it be a lot more code.

Comment: @ExtremeGeek See the edit for one of many short solutions to fill spaces.

Comment: This looks good thanks for your time ! one package I found called [align_positioned](https://pub.dev/packages/align_positioned) and it's very helpful for complicated layout that Row's and Column's can not handle such as to position a child outside it's parent